# VBA code to covert data to a packed format

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a macro that breaks down an excel file to a fixed NL ASCII text file that is a 78 Byte file  27924 Block Size. I then have to send the file to a vendor to pack the data to a 66 Byte file. (includes a space in front of each packed field.) See layouts below. Can this be done in VBA or does it need to be done in a programing software?

---

I start with ASCII:

```
Field #  - Start Pos - Length
    1    -     1     -   4   
    2    -     5     -   6   
    3    -    11     -   2   
    4    -    13     -   6   
    5    -    19     -   6   
    6    -    25     -   1   
    7    -    26     -  21   
    8    -    47     -  10   
    9    -    57     -   1   
    10   -    58     -   1   
    11   -    59     -  20
```

---

and need to end with (packed fields)

```
Field #  - Start Pos - Length - Cobol format    
    1    -    1      -   2    - pic s9(03)comp-3
    2    -    3      -   3    - pic s9(05)comp-3
    3    -    6      -   1    - pic s9(01)comp-3
    4    -    7      -   3    - pic s9(05)comp-3
    5    -   10      -   3    - pic s9(05)comp-3
    6    -   13      -   1    - pic x(01)       
    7    -   14      -  21    - pic x(21)       
    8    -   35      -  10    - pic x(10)       
    9    -   45      -   1    - pic x(01)       
   10    -   46      -   1    - pic x(01)       
   11    -   47      -  20    - pic x(20)
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Comment: I am sure it is possible with VBA but it is 40 years since I used last used Cobol and I have forgotten the exact meaning of "pic s9(03) comp-3".  I know you want a signed, 3-digit number but what format is "comp-3",  VBA is a programming language.How does that differ from programming software?

Comment: (1) After some searching of the web and the dusty corners of my memory, I think I know the format you seek. Yes you can do this with VBA.  However, if the vendor can process comp-3 numeric fields, they can perform the conversion more easily than you can. Why are you performing this conversion? (2) The specification of your input is inadequate.  Do fields 1 to 5 have leading or trailing signs?

Comment: Tony I can honestly say I am not familiar on packed fields so I am not sure what format is "comp-3" is. I am wanting to use VBA in excel to create this process instead of a program outside of excel. Right now it can take the vendor up to two days to send us the return file back as a packed field. to save us time and cost I was wanting to see if this is something I could learn how to do. Yes the text file already has the leading spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Questions remaining from initial “answer”**

Consider field 1:

- If the value is  minus 123 is this held as “-123” or “123-”?
- The output format is given as 2 bytes which is correct for “s9(3) comp-3”. But there is no room for “a space in front of each packed field”.

Does “fixed NL ASCII text file” mean you have 78 bytes lines separated by newline characters?

You say you “have a macro that breaks down an excel file”. Do you want to update that macro or do want to macro that reads the text file and outputs a Cobol file?

Please answer my questions by updating your question

**Possible answer**

I assume you posted your question at work and you will not answer my questions until Monday.  I will have limited internet access next week so I am posting what I hope is a satisfactory answer.  I will respond to your responses when I can.

My interpretation of your question is that you have a macro which builds a file of 358 rows each of 78 bytes terminated by a newline character.  Each row contains 11 fields of which the first six are numeric.  You use a conversion service to create a file which is unchanged except the six numeric fields of each row are converted from ASCII strings to Cobol’s comp3 format.

Within your macro you will have statements such as:

```
RowCrnt = RowCrnt & Range.Value
```

where `RowCrnt` is a string in which the row is being built ready for output and `Range.Value` is an ASCII numeric string taken from a worksheet.

I have written a function so you could replace the above statement with:

```
RowCrnt = RowCrnt & AsciiToComp3(P1, P2, P3, Range.Value)
```

I will explain P1, P2 and P3 later.  With this change, the file created by the macro should be in Cobol format.

I have visually checked that my function creates the output I expect.  However, I have no independent method of testing it.  Perhaps my understanding of comp3 format is faulty.  Perhaps there is a subtle error that is difficult to spot visually.  Perhaps there is more to the conversion than I appreciate.

Suppose your existing macro creates files A1, A2 and so on for different sets of data.  Your vendor has converted files A1, A2 and A3 to files B1, B2 and B3.  You need to check the files created by the updated macro match B1, B2 and B3.

If my function finds something it does not like, it used `Debug.Assert False` to stop execution.  This is very convenient during development but it would frighten a user in a production macro.  None of these `Debug.Assert False` statements should be reached because they indicate an error in the use of the function or in the data it is given to process.  Neither of these should happen so you could decide to leave the function unchanged.  Only you can know what is appropriate.

The parameters P1, P2 and P3 specify the format of the ASCII value to be converted.  The comp3 format created by the function is the smallest that will hold such an ASCII value.  This should be satisfactory for your data.  If you wanted the comp3 value to be larger then specify the maximum size of ASCII data to be larger than the actual maximum.

P1 identifies the position of the sign in the ASCII data:

- -1 means leading sign.  For example: -123 or +123 or 123.
- 0 means no sign
- 1 means trailing sign.  For example: 123- or 123+ or 123.

Comp3 format always reserves a half-byte for a trailing sign even if it is not used.

P2 is the maximum number of integer digits.  So P2=3 if the maximum value is 999 or P2=5 if the maximum value is 99,999.

P3 is the maximum number of decimal digits.  Set P3 =0 if the ASCII value is integer.  Use the local decimal symbol (period or comma) in the ASCII value.

Good luck

```
Option Explicit
Function AsciiToComp3(ByVal SignFmt As Long, ByVal NumIntegerDigitsFmt, _
                      ByVal NumDecimalDigitsFmt As Long, _
                      ByVal AsciiValue As String) As String

  ' * Returns a string which is a Comp-3 version of AsciiValue.

  ' * SignFmt             -1 if AsciiValue has an optional leading sign.  For
  '                          example 12.34 or -12.34
  '                        0 if AsciiValue has no sign.  For example 12.34
  '                        1 if AsciiValue has an optional trailinging sign.
  '                          For example 12.34 or 12.34-
  ' * NumIntegerDigitsFmt  If AsciiValue may not contain a decimal separator,
  '                        the maximum number of digits.
  '                        If AsciiValue may contain a decimal separator, the
  '                        maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal
  '                        separator. The decimal separator is
  '                        Application.DecimalSeparator which returns "." or'
  '                        "," according to local conventions.
  ' * NumDecimalDigitsFmt  If AsciiValue may not contain a decimal separator, 0.
  '                        If AsciiValue may contain a decimal separator, the
  '                        maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal
  '                        separator.
  ' * AsciiValue           The value to be converted to comp-3 format. This
  '                        string must confirm to the format defined by the
  '                        first three parameters. For example: it can only
  '                        contain a sign if SignFmt indicates it can; it can
  '                        only contain a decimal separator if
  '                        NumDecimalDigitsFmt > 0 and the number of digits
  '                        cannot exceed the numbers indicated by
  '                        NumIntegerDigitsFmt and NumDecimalDigitsFmt.

  ' The return string will be sized to hold the largest Ascii value. Increase
  ' NumIntegerDigits and NumDecimalDigits above the true maximum size of
  ' AsciiValue if a larger return string is required. If the return value is to
  ' be signed but AsciiValue is not signed then set Sign to -1 or 1 as though
  ' it could be signed.

  ' The number of bytes in the return string will be:
  '    (NumIntegerDigits + NumDecimalDigits + 1) / 2 rounded up.
  ' The "+ 1" is for the sign.  Space is always allocated for a sign even if
  ' the value is unsigned.
  ' If the expression has to be rounded up, there will be space for one more
  ' integer digit than requested.

  Dim Digit As String
  Dim NumericValue As String
  Dim PosDest As Long
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim PosDecimal As Long
  Dim Positive As Boolean
  Dim PosSrc As Long
  Dim ReturnValue As String

  ' Enlarge NumIntegerDigits if necessary
  If (NumIntegerDigitsFmt + NumDecimalDigitsFmt + 1) Mod 2 = 1 Then
    ' Make output string a whole number of bytes
    NumIntegerDigitsFmt = NumIntegerDigitsFmt + 1
  End If

  ' Decode AsciiValue

  ' If sign present, record value and remove from AsciiValue
  Select Case SignFmt
    Case -1
      Select Case Left(AsciiValue, 1)
        Case "-"
          Positive = False
          AsciiValue = Mid(AsciiValue, 2)  ' Remove sign
        Case "+"
          Positive = True
          AsciiValue = Mid(AsciiValue, 2)  ' Remove sign
        Case Else
          Positive = True
      End Select
    Case 0
      Positive = True
    Case 1
      Select Case Right(AsciiValue, 1)
        Case "-"
          Positive = False
          AsciiValue = Mid(AsciiValue, 1, Len(AsciiValue) - 1) ' Remove sign
        Case "+"
          Positive = True
          AsciiValue = Mid(AsciiValue, 1, Len(AsciiValue) - 1) ' Remove sign
        Case Else
          Positive = True
      End Select
    Case Else
      Debug.Assert False    ' Call error. SignFmt not -1, 0 or 1.
  End Select

  PosDecimal = InStr(1, AsciiValue, Application.DecimalSeparator)

  If PosDecimal > 0 Then
    If NumDecimalDigitsFmt = 0 Then
      ' AsciiValue contains decimal separator but specification says it
      ' should not
      Debug.Assert False
      AsciiToComp3 = "Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
    If PosDecimal > NumIntegerDigitsFmt Or _
       Len(AsciiValue) - PosDecimal > NumDecimalDigitsFmt Then
      ' AsciiValue contains more integer digits or more decimal digits than
      ' allowed by specification
      Debug.Assert False
      AsciiToComp3 = "Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
    ' Pad integer part of AsciiValue with leading zeros to NumIntegerDigits,
    ' discard decimal and
    ' pad decimal part with trailing digits to NumDecimalDigits
    NumericValue = Right(String(NumIntegerDigitsFmt, "0") & Mid(AsciiValue, 1, PosDecimal - 1), NumIntegerDigitsFmt) & _
                   Left(Mid(AsciiValue, PosDecimal + 1) & String(NumDecimalDigitsFmt, "0"), NumDecimalDigitsFmt)
  Else
    ' AsciiValue is all integer
    If Len(AsciiValue) > NumIntegerDigitsFmt Then
      ' AsciiValur contains more integer digits than allowed by specification
      Debug.Assert False
      AsciiToComp3 = "Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
    ' Pad AsciiValue with leading zeros to maximum length
    NumericValue = Right(String(NumIntegerDigitsFmt, "0") & AsciiValue, NumIntegerDigitsFmt)
    If NumDecimalDigitsFmt > 0 Then
      NumericValue = NumericValue & String(NumDecimalDigitsFmt, "0")
    End If
  End If

  ' Create Return value of required length but full of zeros.
  ReturnValue = String((NumIntegerDigitsFmt + NumDecimalDigitsFmt + 1) \ 2, Chr$(0))

  ' Pack Ascii string "ABCEFG" with each pair of ASCII digits becoming one byte
  ' of output string.  Ascii string has odd number of digits with last half byte
  ' reserved for sign.
  ' ABCDEFG  -> ab cd ef g
  PosSrc = 1
  PosDest = 1
  Do While True
    ' Handle digits that are stored in lefthand half of bytes
    Digit = Mid(NumericValue, PosSrc, 1)
    If Digit < "0" Or Digit > "9" Then
     ' Not a decimal digit
      Debug.Assert False
      AsciiToComp3 = "Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
    Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1) = Chr(Val(Digit) * 16)

    PosSrc = PosSrc + 1
    If PosSrc > Len(NumericValue) Then
      ' All digits handled
      Exit Do
    End If

    ' Handle digits that are stored in righthand half of bytes
    Digit = Mid(NumericValue, PosSrc, 1)
    If Digit < "0" Or Digit > "9" Then
     ' Not a decimal digit
      Debug.Assert False
      AsciiToComp3 = "Error"
      Exit Function
    End If
    Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1) = Chr$(Asc(Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1)) Or Val(Digit))

    PosSrc = PosSrc + 1
    PosDest = PosDest + 1

  Loop

  If SignFmt = 0 Then
    ' Comp3 string is unsigned.  Half byte for sign already zero so no action required.
  Else
    If Positive Then
      Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1) = Chr$(Asc(Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1)) Or &HC)
    Else
      Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1) = Chr$(Asc(Mid(ReturnValue, PosDest, 1)) Or &HD)
    End If
  End If

  AsciiToComp3 = ReturnValue

End Function
```